# s3fs fuse mount amazon s3 bucket not working

Tags: mount, debian-wheezy, fuse, modprobe

I am unable to mount my amazon s3 bucket on my debian server. I compiled and installed s3fs successfully as far as I can tell but when I run the mount command:

```
sudo s3fs my-bucket-name /mnt
```

I always get this error:

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

I compiled and installed using the instructions on github:

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Installation-Notes

I also found others saying the solution was either to install fuse-utils or upgrade their kernel. I installed fuse-utils which didn't solve this. I also did a apt-get upgrade and

```
uname -r
```

which prints:

```
3.2.0-4-686-pae
```

which i believe is the latest kernel for my debian 7 server

Further, running:

```
modprobe fuse
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: modprobe: command not found
```

But I found modprobe in `/sbin`

I'm guessing there is a permission issue with modprobe??? Anyone know how to get s3fs to work so I can mount my bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run modprobe as root, for example with sudo.